# how to run a mysql command when mysql server startup?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

i want to run a mysql command START SLAVE; is it possible to do that?

Comment: don't know what your meanings

Comment: before enable replication u must setup a master - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html PS:always replied with @username, otherwise, answerer will not get notified easily

Comment: already success, but when the server restart, i have to type START SLAVE to make the replication take effect

Answer (score 0):

As long as the master is properly configured it's ok to restart the slaves.  They will automatically reissue the "START SLAVE" on restart.

I think if there are replication errors, you may have to fix them or reset replication before restarting the slaves.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/start-slave.html